# PM2 & continuous delivery: How to tell if PM2 process didn't launch?

Tags: node.js, pm2, continuous-delivery

CI/CD services will often use `SUCCEDED` or `FAILED` to display if a deployment succeded and if an error occurred. However, with PM2 this is not so easy.

If you do:
`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` in one of your deployment steps, PM2 will start the process but won't report an error if one of the processes fails. To check it, you would need to execute `pm2 status`, and then judging by the number of restarts and by executing `pm2 logs --err` you would be able to see what happens. I would like PM2 to return a non-zero code or be verbose about a process failing on first launch, rather than what it does now (failing silently).

Is there a native PM2 command that makes it integrate with CI/CD release status reporting easily?

What I want to achieve:

```sh
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
# one of the processes in ecosystem.config.js fails, because eg. the database engine is not running and the driver can't connect to the db
# pm2 prints to stderr and a failure shows up on my CI/CD service. pm2 closes and returns non-zero if it failed to launch one of the processes
```

What's happening currently:

```sh
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
# one of the processes fails
# no error is printed, everything is ok according to pm2. pm2 keeps running and the problematic process fails silently
```

Comment: Right now I'm kinda going to my stage environment and I see I can't connect on eg. port 80, then I SSH into my stage env's machine and run `pm2 status` to see what's up. I guess I should see that immediately in my deployment log on Azure Devops (or anything else, that's just what I use)